# How to debug spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration

We are quite happy with spring-integration except when things do not work as expected. Then it is really difficult to find out what is going on (we are using xml configuration). Can someone point me to the java components behind the spring integration components in order to debug them. For instance: If I have a headerValueRouter, where can I set a breakpoint to find out what is the actual value of the header inside the message, just before the component is doing the routing. Maybe there is even a list int:component->java class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. The list exists, but it isn't so direct, as you may expect. Each xml component goes to some parser. And the last one configure the Spring Integration component(s).
You can find the mapping from source code  of any `AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler` implementation.

Actually, we try to reflect xml-tag names with Java class names. So `<header-value-router>` -> `HeaderValueRouterParser` -> `HeaderValueRouter`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Another thing: Is there a common interface, that all components implement? So that we could create an aspect  or interceptor that surrounds that common interface method for development?

Comment: Suppose `MessageHandler` is for you. From other side there is need to understand what you want to `intercept`...

Comment: I was thinking about intercepting something like handleMessage, so that I can see the state of the message, before and after for a component with a distinct id. 
The other option that we currently use, is to have a debug transformer component, that we can put in for debugging purpose and then delete again, but that's only easy to do in a chain. How expensive is it to surround every standalone si component with a chain in terms of performance and memory consumption?

Comment: Take a look please to the global `<int:wire-tap>` and `<int:logging-channel-adapter>` combination. Anyway I don't see reason to intercept each component, as you can simply intercept channels: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-interceptors

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!