# Spring integration freezing when using WatchServiceDirectoryScanner as int-file:inbound-channel-adapter scanner

Tags: spring-integration

I try to use WatchServiceDirectoryScanner as int-file:inbound-channel-adapter scanner something like this:

```
<int:poller id="globalPoller" default="true" fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10" task-executor="executor"
            error-channel="errorChannel">

</int:poller>
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="100"/>
<int:channel id="filesInChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInAdapter" directory="file:${sas.dir}"
                                   channel="filesInChannel"  auto-startup="true" scanner="watchDirectoryScanner"  >
    <int:poller ref="globalPoller"/>

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<bean id="nioLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" />

<bean id="watchDirectoryScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner" >
    <constructor-arg value="file:${sas.dir}"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="filter" ref="compositeFilter" />
    <property name="locker" ref="nioLocker"/>
</bean>
```

But the application did not run and there is no error log appear. Anyone has experience about that? Where should i put debug point? .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run with DEBUG logging - if you see no activity in the log, the poller thread is stuck somewhere - use `jstack` to take a thread dump to find out why.

Comment: Thanks Garry for the answer. Finally i found the error using this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141431/how-to-debug-spring-integration.